# How to update an object in Sequel without firing any of the before/after/around hooks

Tags: ruby, sequel

Is there a way to update a model object without firing any of the before/after/around hooks? There seems to be a way to do this with validations but not with hooks in [`skip_validation_on_next_save!`](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Model/InstanceMethods.html#method-i-skip_validation_on_next_save-21).

For example:

```
posts.where(id = 5).update(state: 'archived')
```

How can I write this update statement so that it won't run the `after_save` hook?

[Sequel hooks](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/model_hooks.rdoc) has more information.

Comment: "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)" is your friend. You're asking us to write a tutorial because we don't know your expertise level or what you tried.

Comment: Thanks, I provided more detail and an example.

Comment: I'd recommend taking this to "[Sequel Talk](http://groups.google.com/group/sequel-talk)" or the Sequel IRC at irc://irc.freenode.net/sequel. The real experts hang out there.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation has a section on how to skip model hooks: https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/model_hooks.rdoc#skipping-hooks-

Essentially:

```rb
posts.where(id: 5).this.update state: 'archived'
```

`#this` will return a `Sequel::Dataset` instance, which will skip any model hooks (since you're not dealing with a model instance anymore).